# Filter Result Best match result at top and then follow remaining results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, express, mongoose

I am developing one city filter in mongodb and nodejs with list of city with checkbox like this

- city name 1
- city name 2
- city name 3
- city name 4

once we click on any city or multiple city then we receive data with related to that city with following code.

```
var query = {city:{ $in:city }};

 posts.find(query, {} , function(e,docs){
            res.json(docs);
  });
```

through query i just pass the city as array and receive Data..But my requirement is :

1.Suppose if i selected any 1 or 2 city then that city result come first and remaining city follow after that city even if those city not selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide sample document of city ?

Comment: http://puu.sh/kma6N/0a94e633a7.png   u can take any  city i have attached one screenshot...

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible from one query. Why can you try to execute 2 separate query and save the result in one resultset.

Comment: so which two query do you think best suited to this condition and then merge it to one resultset..

Answer (score 0):

```
Query1 : db.city.find({name:{$in:["Bangalore"]}})
Query2 - db.city.find({name:{$nin:["Bangalore"]}})

**

 - Edit

**

> var result = []; //Define an empty Array
> var cur = db.city.aggregate([{$match:{name:{$in:["Bangalore","Delhi"]}}}]); //Get matching city and save it in cursor
> while(cur.hasNext()){   result.push(cur.next()) } // Retrieve the cursor data and push it in array  
> var cur = db.city.aggregate([{$match:{name:{$nin:["Bangalore","Delhi"]}}}]); // Get non matching city and save it in cursor (should be new variable)
> while(cur.hasNext()){   result.push(cur.next()) }
> for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){printjson(result[i])}

This will give you expected result. Hope you are expecting the same :)
```

Comment: i have try this...i need a result where first $in array result there after $nin array content will display... we can pass this query as well {city:{ $in:city }},{city:{ $nin:city }}  but my main concern sorting order..

Comment: I understand your concern, I am not sure about how you do in nodejs but in java i will have an arraylist, i will execute these 2 query sequentially and add into arraylist which maintain the insertion order. Hope it will help :)